# $.mobile is undefined (Worklight + jQuery Mobile)

Tags: jquery-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

I have main html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>     
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Home.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme-addon.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8" />

    <script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body id="content" style="display: none">

    <div data-role="page" id="homePage">
        <div data-role="header"><div class="ui-title">Home</div></div>
        <div data-role="content" style="text-align: center">
            <a data-role="button" id="login" class="fullWidth">Login</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
    <script src="js/Home.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="js/messages.js"></script>

</body>
```

Then in Home.js:

```
// Worklight comes with the jQuery framework bundled inside. If you do not want to use it, please comment out the line below.
window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;

function wlCommonInit(){
    // Common initialization code goes here
}

$("#homePage").live('pagecreate', function(event,ui) {
    $('#login').click(function(){
        $.mobile.changePage($('#nextPage.html'));
    });
});
```

When I tap on login button, it gives error `$.mobile is undefined` on this line:

```
$.mobile.changePage($('#nextPage.html'));
```

Is there anyone can give insight what's wrong with my code? I believe I do the right things? In addition, I use **5.0.2.407-developer-edition** Worklight version.

Comment: Because both jquery and jquery mobile should be placed in `<head>` and jquery should be loaded before jquery mobile

Comment: It makes my app becomes plain html page..

Comment: Ok at least load jquery first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally I solved this issue by:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
    var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

and later in js:

```
jq.mobile.changePage("the.html");
```

instead of

```
$.mobile.changePage("the.html");
```

Comment: Note: if using newer versions of Worklight this would not be required to do.

Answer (score 0):

Worklight is already bundled with jQuery, so you shouldn't add it a second time as you did at the bottom of the HTML. Also, you shouldn't place it at the bottom anyway, rather in the HEAD - remove that line.

Additionally, move the reference to jQuery Mobile to the HEAD a as well.

Using Worklight 5.0.6.1 (the latest version, which you seem not to use) and jQuery Mobile 1.3.1, I created a new project and application, and modified the HTML as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>testapp</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/testapp.css">
    <script src="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css"></script>
    <script src="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
</head>
<body id="content" style="display: none;">
    <div data-role="page">
    testapp

    </div>
    <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
    <script src="js/testapp.js"></script>
    <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

1. I place the minified .css and .js files in a folder, and referenced them inside the HEAD element.
2. I added   inside the BODY element.
3. Build All and Deploy
4. Preview via Worklight Console

Works...
I suggest you start small like the above (including using the latest versions of Worklight and jQuery Mobile), and build on that (working) foundation).

You can get the latest version of Worklight from the Eclipse Marketplace (in Eclipse, look at the Help menu >> Marketplace).

Comment: Ok. So I remove the `jquery` line and move `jquery.mobile` to `head` and left `initOption.js`, `Home.js` and `message.js` in bottom of the body, but my app becomes a plain html page.

Comment: Update the code snippets in your question with how it looks like after the changes.

Comment: Hi Idan, sorry for late reply, I was busy yesterday. I have tried using your code but still no luck :( Please see my edited code and 1 line on bottom. I can't use the latest version because of there will be some errors to occur in Console and I also need to include the jquery.min.js to prevent any undefined error.

Comment: 5.0.2 is a VERY old version, my mark-up above will not work with that version. need to think about it. Why will the console not work with 5.0.6? please explain.

Comment: Oh is it a very old version? I don't know since I am very new to Worklight and got it from my supervisor. With your code, there is syntax error in jquery-mobile. I think maybe it's better to update the Worklight version first. I will update it tonight since proxy blocks it in my office.

Comment: Hi Idan Adar, I managed to solve this by declaring `var jq = jQuery.noConflict();` and use `jq.mobile.changePage` instead of `$.mobile.changePage`

Comment: Can you add that as an Answer and mark this question as Answered please?

Comment: I think there's a mistake in the code above.  Shouldn't `<script src="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css"></script>` be replaced by `<link rel="stylesheet" href="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />` ?