# Worklight - jquery mobile 1.3.1 with jquery 1.10.2 - TypeError: $.mobile is undefined

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

My setup is Worklight 6.0.0.1, Jquery mobile 1.3.1 and jquery 1.10.2.

When I import them this way:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>KlapprJQ</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png">
        <link href="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/KlapprJQ.css">
        <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
        <script src="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body id="content">
    <div data-role="page">
        <!-- Empty page to initialize jQuery mobile -->
    </div>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
        <script src="js/KlapprJQ.js"></script>
        <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
        <script src="js/login.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I get the following error:

```
    TypeError: $.mobile is undefined
```

When I try to do this:

```
    $.mobile.loadPage("views/dialog.html", {});
$.mobile.changePage("views/login.html", {});
```

What are the best practices with jquery mobile in Worklight?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16577872/mobile-is-undefined-worklight-jquery-mobile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include jQuery Mobile after jQuery library

```
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
    <script src="js/KlapprJQ.js"></script>
    <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
    <script src="js/login.js"></script>
```