# jQuery $.mobile library is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have linked jQuery and jQuery mobile to my code. I got this error in the console:

```
TypeError: $.mobile is undefined
```

I have rechecked the URL and all are correct, I have update the files(jQuery, jQuery mobile) and the issue is still exists.
I have place the jquery.js before jquery.mobile.js

This is my code:

```
    <script src="JS/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
    <script src="JS/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="JS/code.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and it's on the end of the file.
the content of code.js: http://pastebin.com/3LTcxs9S

Comment: Paste the code *here*, also why double slashes?

Comment: there u go: http://pastebin.com/tbHf25Le
i tried also this way, it was before with "http://"

Comment: @AndrewL. `//` means use the same protocol as the page. It's commonly used to deal with both `http://` and `https://` protocols. However, do aware that it won't work in protocols other than those two including `file://`.

Comment: Noticed you're using local jQuery and then jQuery Mobile externally (from a CDN), does it work if you try loading jQuery externally as well? Not an answer necessarily, just some troubleshooting. You could try the one from CDNJS: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery

Comment: thx guys for your respond
but its still dont work, i replaced // with https://
and load both libary from a cdn and its still dont work :(
i need only the option to detect the swipeleft/swiperight event.
there is another option?

Comment: you have a confict in libraries -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16577872/mobile-is-undefined-worklight-jquery-mobile -- however if you just want to detect swipe gestures then use hammer js http://hammerjs.github.io/ or touchswipe http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/touchSwipe/demos/index.html rather than jquery mobile

Comment: thx for your response.
i  tried touchswipe liabry and when i try to multiple the swipeleft and swiperight event toghether i get error when i try to trigger it.
`$('#carousel2,#carousel').swipe( {
  swipe:function(event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount, fingerData) {
   if(direction == 'left'){
    $(this).carousel('next');
   }else if(direction == 'right'){
    $(this).carousel('perv');
   }
  },
   threshold:0
 });`
and i get this error **TypeError: e[g] is not a function
 

...(this,f)),"number"==typeof b?e.to(b):g?e[g]():f.interval&&e.pause().cycle()})}va...

 **

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"> 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile- 
1.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

try this by replacing your code

NOTE* put jquery mobile script at last after putting all jquery library scripts, im sure it will work